# Using "never" "want" and "again" in a sentence

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I want to translate the phrase "I never want to see your hairy butt again" (it's a joke for a wedding speech).

My two classes of German have taught me it should look something like this:

> Ich will nie dein haariger Arsch sehen

But I'm having difficulty fitting in "again". I think it would be "noch einmal" but I'm confused as where to put it and I'm worried I'm just translating literally.

Comment: Side note: a much more appropriate translation to *butt* in the context of a wedding speech would be [*Hintern*](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Butt).

Comment: I have the impression *hairy butt* is a pun. English puns do not translate well into German. Could you explain it, so we can find the matching German expression?

Comment: @Janka I don't think it's a pun.

Comment: Never say never again, again!

Comment: It's meant to be very literal, as I did see my friend's hairy butt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

German allows you to toss around the components of a sentence for emphasis, and you should make use of this opportunity. The first component is the topic, it gets the most emphasis. The last component gets the second most emphasis. If there are verbs at the end, the second-last component mingles into that.

I think this is a speech the father gives to his son. I added *bei mir* for *at my place*. This gives even more permutations.

> **Ich** will deinen haarigen Hintern bei mir *nie wieder sehen*.
>
> **Nie wieder** will ich deinen haarigen Hintern *bei mir sehen*.
>
> **Deinen haarigen Hintern** will ich bei mir *nie wieder sehen*.
>
> **Bei mir** will ich deinen haarigen Hintern *nie wieder sehen*.

etc. etc.

The only components with a fixed position are the finite verb form *will* (always second position), and the infinitive *sehen* (always at the end). And, if the subject isn't the topic, it follows the finite verb.

---

About **again**, this word has dozens of possible translations into German and it's sometimes tricky which one to use.

> Das mache ich nicht noch einmal.
>
> Das mache ich nie wieder.

Comment: +1, but since the OP mentioned "noch einmal" it would be nice if you also explained the difference between "never again" ("nie wieder") and "not again" ("nicht noch einmal"/"nicht nochmal").

Comment: adding "bei mir" gives you more permutations, but adding it depends on context, bloats it up unnecessarly and should be omitted in this case.

Comment: reading longer your suggests, I came to conclusion the OP wants to express that the speaker was responsible to take care of the arse-owner which is now a grown up and due to marriage someone else has to take care in case of any fostering. And that the english "idiom" might originate in another language / culture.

Comment: I'm the best man, and am trying not to embarrass my friend too much, just a little bit. Thank you for the explanations, they were very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Ich will nie wieder deinen haarigen Arsch sehen.

Comment: _Ich will deinen haarigen Arsch nie wieder sehen_ sounds way more natural to me. Couldn't tell you why though.

Comment: @sgf: I would say: because the "nie wieder sehen" is emphasized for this speech. not the arse.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm could you explain the emphasis for me please? Am I correct in assuming "Ich will deinen haarigen...." emphasizes the arse?

Comment: @IanCheng: somewhat tricky: regardless the word order there is emphazise while speaking. So this "overrules" the written word. Thus the stress is like "deinen haarigen Hintern" vs. "nie wieder" - the first is the specific body part, the latter more general. So the arse is either main topic or just example. If i would stress on the arse, I would need a humorous situation e.g. where I saved arse-owners live and hope to stay healthy in future. Otherwise it would feel like "what has a butt made for a crime?" See Janka's answer for grammatics.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm thank you for the explanation! I'm guessing emphasis is much easier in conversation rather than writing.